# cmsis fft initial function

Tags: fft, arm

I wanted to get a Fourier transform on the stm32 MCU
With the help of cmsis functions

But I encountered the problem of lack of memory while the buffer size was small.

After a lot of trouble, by checking the map file, I realized that a function consumes a lot of memory when called, about 150 KB. `arm_rfft_fast_init_f32()`

Do you have any suggestions to reduce the memory size? This function sets the initial conditions, but it requires a lot of memory.

Now, I am not in a position to quickly provide hardware with more memory.

here is the Code

```
------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
# include <math.h>
# include "arm_math.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define  FFT_SIZE       32
#define  F_PI   3.14

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

uint16_t i;

  //FFT Variables
  arm_rfft_fast_instance_f32 s;
  enum windowing{hamming=0,hanning,Blackman_Harris,nuttall,Blackman_Nutall } window_type ;
 
float window_multipliers[FFT_SIZE] = {0};  //coefficent for window selecting
float fft_input[FFT_SIZE] ;
float fft_output[FFT_SIZE];//output of FFt that is a complex number but have fft_size/2   point inherent
float fft_mag[FFT_SIZE/2];//magnitude of FFT
 
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    window_type=hamming;
    switch (window_type){
    case hamming:
        for ( i = 0; i < FFT_SIZE; i++) {
            window_multipliers[i] = 0.54f - 0.46f * arm_cos_f32((2.0f * F_PI * (float32_t)i) / ((float32_t)FFT_SIZE - 1.0f));
        }
    break;

    case Blackman_Harris:
        for ( i = 0; i < FFT_SIZE; i++){
            window_multipliers[i] = 0.35875f - 0.48829f * arm_cos_f32(2.0f * F_PI * (float32_t)i / ((float32_t)FFT_SIZE - 1.0f)) +0.14128f * arm_cos_f32(4.0f * F_PI * (float32_t)i / ((float32_t)FFT_SIZE - 1.0f)) -0.01168f * arm_cos_f32(6.0f * F_PI * (float32_t)i / ((float32_t)FFT_SIZE - 1.0f));  
        }
    break;

    case nuttall:
        for ( i = 0; i < FFT_SIZE; i++){
        window_multipliers[i] = 0.355768f - 0.487396f * arm_cos_f32(2.0f * F_PI * (float32_t)i / ((float32_t)FFT_SIZE - 1.0f)) +0.144232f * arm_cos_f32(4.0f * F_PI * (float32_t)i / ((float32_t)FFT_SIZE - 1.0f)) -0.012604 * arm_cos_f32(6.0f * F_PI * (float32_t)i / ((float32_t)FFT_SIZE - 1.0f));
        }
    break;
    
    case Blackman_Nutall:
        for ( i = 0; i < FFT_SIZE; i++){
                window_multipliers[i] = 0.3635819f - 0.4891775f * arm_cos_f32(2.0f * F_PI * (float32_t)i / ((float32_t)FFT_SIZE - 1.0f)) +0.1365995f * arm_cos_f32(4.0f * F_PI * (float32_t)i / ((float32_t)FFT_SIZE - 1.0f)) - 0.0106411f * arm_cos_f32(6.0f * F_PI * (float32_t)i / ((float32_t)FFT_SIZE - 1.0f));
        }
    break;
    
    case hanning :
        for ( i = 0; i < FFT_SIZE; i++){
        window_multipliers[i] = 0.5f * (1.0f - arm_cos_f32(2.0f * F_PI * (float32_t)i / (float32_t)FFT_SIZE));
        }   
    break;
}//window type switch
/*
****problem maker**    */
  arm_rfft_fast_init_f32(&s,FFT_SIZE);

  

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      for(i=0; i<FFT_SIZE ;i++){ 
          fft_input[i]=arm_sin_f32 ( (2*F_PI*i) / 360 );
          HAL_Delay(1);
      }
      
      //do windowing 
      arm_mult_f32(window_multipliers ,fft_input,fft_input,FFT_SIZE);
    
  arm_rfft_fast_f32(&s,fft_input,fft_input,0);       //Q: can  we use same buffer for in& out of FFT 
      
//calculate  magnitude of  the complex output of FFt 
      arm_cmplx_mag_f32(fft_input,fft_mag,FFT_SIZE);
.
.
.
```

here  picture of eror [image]

Comment: 150 kB is indeed much. What's the transform size?

Comment: @MarcusMüller   In fact, I first selected the size 512 and it gave 2 memory errors, and then I changed the size to 32, one of the errors was resolved, but the second error still remained, and it was related to the code that I attached, and even in the map file, this memory was related to calling This function    `arm_rfft_fast_init_f32()`

Comment: Can you please add the exact invocation of `arm_rfft_fast_init_f32` to your question? We need to know all arguments.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  i add code to question   but i cant add mapfile

Comment: You can open an issue at [github](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS-DSP/issues)

Comment: wait, you just posted a map file; are we talking 150 kB in program memory, or are we talking 150 kB of scratch space?

Comment: @MarcusMüller  I don't understand what you mean by scratch space, and I searched to see what it has to do with micro, but I didn't understand.
   I opened an issue on Github and added the map file there <https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS-DSP/issues/91>, and also put the error image here.

Comment: Ah the memory consumption doesn't happen when you *call* the function (i.e., at *runtime*), but when you compile...

Comment: @MarcusMüller  Do you mean that if I have a MCU with more memory, it will be fixed? So that it doesn't take much memory after compilation and only needs more memory during compilation?
   Probably this micro has enough memory! (Of course, after compiling, right?)
  So what should be done now? Should I use another chip?

Comment: don't know! Would need to have intimate knowledge of your linker scripts and compile options. My suspicion is that for some reason you're including unused symbols in your image.